# RemoteWebDriver generate "Secure Connection Failed" with firefox 43 and above

Tags: selenium

when I do the following line

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), oCapabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
```

Firefox generate the error "Secure Connection Failed". I'm guessing the proxy is blocked, how can I prevent it?

I'm following this page without success:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-) Had to update selenium drivers.

2-) Also that firefox was always opening as if it was the first use. to prevent this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile.ToBase64String());  // profile MUST be converted to this type
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(remoteAddress), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
```